# How to display a loading screen while fetching data with Volley in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley

I want to load userdata e.g. Username and Email from my database into some Text Views. When the activity opens there is always a delay. I'm fetching the data in the onCreate method.
How do I display a loading icon, or can I prevent this delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the Android `ProgressBar` widget; doc [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html). Or show some splash screen, which can either be an `ImageView` or even it's own layout.
The key is to show the `ProgressBar`/splash screen before initiating the Volley request. Then in the Volley request's `onResponse()` or `onResponseError()`, show the resulting data or an error message respectively, and of course hide the `ProgressBar` or splash screen.